# Typescript object initializer error for optional with default property declared in constructor shorthand

Tags: typescript

When declaring a constructor like this:

```
export class Test {

    constructor(
            public name: string,
            public value: number = -1) {
    }
}
```

Keeping in mind that in the official TS documentation it is written :

> Default-initialized parameters that come after all required parameters are treated as optional, and just like optional parameters, can be omitted when calling their respective function.

When trying this:

```
let test: Test = {name: 'xxx'};
```

I get this error:

> TS2741: Property 'value' is missing in type '{ name: string; }' but required in type 'Test'.

And if I try to explicitly declare the parameter optional:

```
public value?: number = -1
```

I get this one:

> TS1015: Parameter cannot have question mark and initializer.

Comment: `let test = new Test('xxx');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to accomplish what you want. You need to declare `value` as a `public` property on your class and make it optional. Then you can take in a parameter in your constructor called `value` which will be local to that constructor function. Then in your constructor you can assign the value in the 'value' parameter to the 'value' property on your 'class' instance object.

```
class Test {
    public value?: number;

    constructor(
            public name: string,
        value: number = -1) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

const a: Test = { name: '' };
const b= new Test('');
```

Comment: Thanks I think I confused constructor parameter with class property, the parameter is optional but this is not making the property optional. I wanted a shorter way of doing it I guess.